# How to access System Timer Interrupts in Rust

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, interrupt

It seems that Rust would have a simple way to access system timer interrupts, but, alas, I'm not finding it.

I am running a stepper motor from a Raspberry Pi Compute 3+ module with Debian implemented via the Rust lang. I need to 'pulse' the GPIO pin to move the stepper motor (essentially PWM).

On Particle's Photon this is accomplished like this:

```
Timer timerPeriodic(100, []() {   pulseStepper();   });
timerPeriodic.start();
```

This would execute 10 times a second. I need something like this in Rust.

Yes, I know I can setup a loop and do constant polling with something like this:

```
if (millis() - this->old_time >= this->speed) { ... }
```

But I would rather stay away from polling and use event driven architectures instead (of course, I'm open to suggestions why polling might be better anyway for this situation).

Comment: And, I know that the Rust crate tokio exists which may handle this, but it seems way overkill to include the entire tokio library to achieve such a simple task.

Comment: Well, aren't you including the Photon's library when you do it in C++? Why would you expect Rust to have something built-in but be fine with using a library in C++?

Comment: I'm not expecting the core Rust lang to have a high level library built in, necessarily. I'm just looking for a lightweight solution. And, if Particle has written a library in C to access System Timers, surely, there must be a way to do access System Timers in Rust -- even if its not as convenient as a two liner.

Comment: So, a "just use [FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html)" answer would be fine with you?

Comment: `with Debian` - which "system timers" do you have in mind? There is no such thing as "system timer interrupt" on linux on user side. Unless they implemented custom module for that. If they access some "system timers" (somehow I don't believe such thing exists), you surely will see calls in `strace` to those timers. Mostly such things are implemented as a thread that just waits for some action. And you can do the same in rust.

Comment: Mark Phillipp wrote an article detailing the two system timers present on the raspberry pi -- one of which is the ARM AP804. He then gets into low level ARM assembly to access it. I'm coming into this whole system timer thing without much knowledge of low level computer firmware, so I fully acknowledge I may be making assumptions about whats possible on the C/Rust level. --- article ref: https://www.studica.com/blog/raspberry-pi-timer-embedded-environments

Comment: This article runs on a bare Pi (ie. without an OS) and accesses the timer using specialized assembly. If you want to do the same in Rust, I suggest you start by reading some of the bare-metal tutorials like https://medium.com/@thiagopnts/raspberry-pi-bare-metal-programming-with-rust-a6f145e84024 you can't access those timers with an OS running (in any language).

Comment: Thanks Jmb for the reply. I’m starting to gather that. The timer does indeed seem to be only accessed via the Linux kernel. For this reason, among others, it seems senseless to use Raspberry Pi for most embedded programming needs.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not clear that it uses the system timer interrupts in its implementation, the following may suit your needs.

```
    let timer = timer::Timer::new();
    
    let _guard = timer.schedule_repeating(chrono::Duration::milliseconds(100), move || {
        pulseStepper();
    });
```

For more details, see the docs at

https://docs.rs/timer/latest/timer/struct.Timer.html